# Need my renaming function in my script to work with a specific directory other than directory script is located

Tags: batch-file, set, rename

I have what I think should be a simple problem to solve but don't know how to achieve it as someone already helped me with the code below.

I'm running the below code to rename my files

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir *RETOUCH* /b') do (
    set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.RETOUCH=!"
    ren "%%a" "!name!"
)
```

I need it to work with this directory

```
"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\"
```

Currently it only works in the same location as files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the batch code for your task with some simplifications:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\*RETOUCH*") do (
    set "name=%%~nxa"
    set "name=!name:.RETOUCH=!"
    ren "%%~a" "!name!"
)
endlocal
```

To understand how it works, open a command prompt window, execute the following commands and read help output for each command:

- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `ren /?`

Comment: Works perfect, thank you much. 

Also, I try to type my questions clean with spaces and formatting but I guess I don't know how to do it correctly on here as it always bunches everything together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Pushd "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\"
  for /f %%a in ('dir *RETOUCH* /b') do (
    set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.RETOUCH=!"
    ren "%%a" "!name!"
  )
 popd

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\"
  for /f %%a in ('dir *RETOUCH* /b') do (
    set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.RETOUCH=!"
    ren "%%a" "!name!"
  )

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "myDir=C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Uploads\%studiosetnumber%\%ymd%\"
  for /f %%a in ('dir "%myDir%" *RETOUCH* /b') do (
    set "name=%%a"&set "name=!name:.RETOUCH=!"
    ren "%%a" "!name!"
  )
```

Comment: The last one does not work as `dir` returns just the file name without path and therefore `ren` fails. See the really simple solution in my answer.